# iMacros Multipage Loop Extraction

Tags: macros, scripting, imacros, data-extraction

I am using iMacros v9.00.2379. WHat I am currently trying to achieve is to go onto a product page, scrap the title, additional information, image (if possible) and description. The browser then goes back and repeats the process for pages structured in the exact same way. So far I have tried;

```
VERSION BUILD=7401598
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/books/2020/ref=s9_dnav_bw_ir11_z?                    pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-  4&pf_rd_r=08RVC6ADSMV3711JH9VS&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1759594182&pf_rd_i=1
TAG POS={{!loop}} TYPE=TD FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=TXT:*
TAG POS=8 TYPE=TD FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=6 TYPE=TD FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=20 TYPE=TD FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=24 TYPE=TD FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=22 TYPE=TD FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=34 TYPE=TD FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=38 TYPE=TD FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=42 TYPE=TD FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=46 TYPE=TD FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=66 TYPE=TD FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=CLASS:labelBold EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\iMacrosExports\ FILE=Extract_{{!NOW:ddmmyy_hhnnss}}.csv
WAIT SECONDS=2
BACK
```

The site in question is http://www.bookdepository.com but today it's down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked fine for me.

"websiteloop" in last line is your above code which will extract the data from the links.

Links you should provide in "var urls" section as I did it with "www.ab.com/first.html" "www.ba.com/second.html" etc...

Script:

```
var urls = 
['http://www.ab.com/first.html',
'http://www.ba.com/second.html
etc....']

for (var i in urls) {
var url = urls[i];
var returnCode = iimPlay('CODE: URL GOTO='+url);
iimPlay("C:\\Users\\venkat\\Documents\\iMacros\\Macros\\#websiteloop");
}
```